# RESOLVED Prepared Insert Not Functioning

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So ive been asked to make a comment system and store the information in the DB but ive been trying to make this work for a  couple of hours but without luck.

```
 $req = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (bank_id, date_created, comment, user_id) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?,  (SELECT accounts.id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.first_name=?))');          
 $data = $req->execute([$_COOKIE['acteur_id'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST['author']]);
```

From what I undertand this should normally work, i checked my db to make sure everything is identical and checking the $_POST if they are the right value.
Heres the full .php

```
<?php
  include_once('session.php');
  // Insert new comment:
  if (isset($_COOKIE['acteur_id'])) {
     echo "value is :" . $_COOKIE['acteur_id'];
    try {
      //If any of the area is empty 
      if ($_POST['author'] == '' || $_POST['date'] == '' || $_POST['comment'] == '')  {
        throw new Exception("veuillez remplir tous les champs avant d'envoyer");
      } else {
        include_once('config.php');
        

                $sql = $connection-> prepare("SELECT comment_username FROM posts WHERE comment_username = ?");
                $sql-> execute([$_SESSION['username']]);
                  //If Rowcount is higher than 0 then its allready commented.
                if ($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
                  header('Location: acteur.php?acteur='. $_COOKIE['acteur_id'] .'');
                exit();
                };        
                
                //$req = $connection-> prepare("INSERT INTO posts (bank_id, comment, date_created, comment_username) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?)");
                $req = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (bank_id, date_created, comment, user_id) VALUES (?, NOW(), ?,  (SELECT accounts.id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.first_name=?))');
                $data = $req->execute([$_COOKIE['acteur_id'], $_POST['comment'], $_POST['author']]);

        header('Location: acteur.php?acteur='. $_COOKIE['acteur_id'] .'');
        exit();
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      $_SESSION['error'] = $e->getMessage();
      header('Location: acteur.php?acteur='. $_COOKIE['acteur_id'] .'');
      exit();
    }
  }
?>
```

Here is the Db for 'posts'

date_created / date /
bank_id /index/ int(11)
comment / varchar
comment_username / varchar
comment_id / primary key / int(11)
user_id / int(11)

If anyone has any ideas or even  a different way to insert the ID from a user from another account into the db 'posts' I am all ears.
Thank you.

EDIT: Something strange I found out maybe this can give a bit more information on whats happening. If i do my first statement (the one thats in //comment, it does not work as long as i have the extra row (user_id) in my table 'posts', this has not happened to me yet and not sure whats going on.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: I am not getting any errors when i run this unfortunatly.

EDIT: I am rather new to php so I have tried a vardump(); and die to see if i have any errors but got nothing.

Comment: You need to figure out where things are going wrong. Is the sql statement being prepared? Is it being executed? Is it possible that in your tests, a comment was already inserted, thus preventing further comments from being inserted?

Comment: From what i understand I think my problem comes from 
(SELECT accounts.id FROM accounts WHERE accounts.first_name=?))');

My DB is currently empty with no comments inserted. I have written down a simpler statment but that excludes th SELECT to grab the ID in another table and it works fine.

Comment: Enable pdo error handling: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: Read through the article you linked in and i have enabled the PDO error handling but unfortunatly no errors appear.

Comment: Resolved: my ariable NOW() was not defined so just added 
$today = date("Y-m-d");
and everything works 
Thanks for the help wetmarble and ADyson for youre help and comments that pdo error handling helped me for other stuff  :)